# Regex Error in .htaccess with hash mark in URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

What am I doing wrong with this regex.

```
My requested url
http://domain.com/local/v11/full/#Q73Ps/
```

What I have in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^local/v11/full/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ local/v11/server/full.php?token=$1
```

The above rule always give me 404 error.

**Added Logs**

```
related apache error
[Thu Feb 09 14:04:21 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /path/to/folder/local/v11/full

related access logs
[09/Feb/2012:14:16:54 +0500] "GET /local/v11/full/ HTTP/1.1" 404 340

no re-write log
```

Comment: Did you check your rewrite log to see where it is trying to send you?

Comment: Is that the exact error?? File does not exist: /path/to/folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you try to access: `http://domain.com/local/v11/full/#Q73Ps/` browser send request for: `http://domain.com/local/v11/full/` and doesn't consider `#Q73Ps/`  as part of URL. if you want to get your rewrite rule working replace `#` in URL with `%23` and it will work.

Comment: @UmairAshraf you can use `_` or `-`.

Comment: @UmairAshraf  ThinkingMonkey is right and it's better to use - rather than underscore(_)